# PHP 2 Arrays Get Values From Both Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I dont want to merge or intersect or diff I just want to get both values from both arrays with matching keys regardless of values matching or not.

example data

```
array1 ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b' )
array2 ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'c' )
```

foreach

```
echo "Key: ".$key." Value1: ".$v1." Value2: ".$v2."";
```

I would like this as the output

```
Key: 0 Value1: a Value2: a
Key: 1 Value1: b Value2: c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both arrays have the exact same keys, you can iterate through one of them while printing values from both.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
   echo "Key: ".$key." Value1: ".$array1[$key]." Value2: ".$array2[$key];
}
```

Comment: OMG THIS WORKED THANKS SO MUCH <3

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1= array( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b' );
$array2=array ( 0 => 'z', 1 => 'c' );
foreach ($array1 as $k=>$val){
   //safe in case of key does't exist in second array
   if(array_key_exists($k,$array2))
     echo $k . " Value1: ".$val ." Value2: ". $array2[$k].'<br>';
   else
     echo $k . " Value1: ".$val
}
```